# How to parse json first objects without key in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I need to parse json form this link *https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json*

This file stores the country names as a key, and as city values located in these countries

How to pull the city by the key of the country I know, here is an example with China

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self JSONFromFile]; 
NSArray *city = [dict objectForKey:@"China"]; 
NSLog(@"Colour name: %@", city);
```

But I first need to get all the names of countries, which would then give the user the choice of the country for further action.

Comment: It's not clear what you want but if you're looking to discover all the keys in a dictionary you can use `[dict allKeys]`

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the JSON response and store it in a Dictionary and then use the below code to iterate each key value pair in this dictionary.

**For Objective C**

```
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id value, BOOL* stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@ => %@", key, value);
    // This block will iterate for each (key,value) pair in the dictionary.
}];
```

**For Swift 3.0**

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    print(key, value)
    // This block will iterate for each (key,value) pair in the dictionary.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to dictionary key (Country) than Simple you can get as this

```
NSArray* arrayCountyName = [Yourdict allKeys]; // list of your country names
```